# Start up yocto qemu emulator from python

Tags: python-3.x, yocto, qemu

I'm trying to benchmark a qemu emulator running various yocto versions, using a python program on the machine I'm using the build the emulators, an 18.04.1-Ubuntu, using python 3.6.

I'm using [qemu.qmp](https://qemu.readthedocs.io/projects/python-qemu-qmp/en/latest/main.html) and I keep getting:

> qemu.qmp.ConnectError Failed to establish connection: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

I suspect that it's because even though I'm running my program from the yocto's build dir after running `source oe-init-build-env`, the new process the python runs does not have this command run and I'm not sure how to incorporate it into my code.

My code:

```
import qemu.qmp
from time import perf_counter
from time import sleep

from utils.constant_vars import CONSTANTS
from utils.log import log

async def benchmark_qemu() -> bool:
    log.info("Started running benchmark_qemu")

    start_time = perf_counter()
    log.info(f"Started benchmarking at {start_time}")

    try:
        qemu_client = qemu.qmp.QMPClient("test-vm")
        await qemu_client.connect("qmp.sock")

        time_passed = 0

        while time_passed < CONSTANTS.TIMEOUT:
            res = await qemu_client.execute("query-status")

            if res["status"] == "running":
                end_time = perf_counter()
                log.info("Qemu machine is running")
                log.info(f"Ended benchmarking at {end_time}")
                CONSTANTS.QEMU_MACHINE_BOOT_TIME = end_time - start_time
                return True

        time_passed += 1
        sleep(1)
    except qemu.qmp.ConnectError as e:
        log.critical(f"Failed to spin up qemu machine:\n{e}")
        return False

    log.critical(f"Failed to bring up protected {CONSTANTS.PLATFORM} {CONSTANTS.QEMU_ARCH} machine")
    return False
```

If it matters, I'm running the qemu emulator with `runqemu core-image-minimal ext4 nographic` which works in cli on the machine used to build the yocto image.